# Mapping a range to another range

Tags: netlogo

I have range from 0 to a which I have to proportionally map to a range from b to c. How to achieve this in NetLogo.

```
0 to a -> b to c
 [0 a] -> [b c]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your input is `x`, then:

```
b + (x / a) * (c - b)
```

Comment: what if it is [d to a] -> [b to c] . That is `d` instead of  0.

Comment: Did you try to solve it yourself? If so, open a new question and show your best attempt.